# Dual Battery Thinkpad shuts down at 50%

Tags: debian, gnome, power-management, openbox, battery

My thinkpad t470s likes to cut off with no warning when one of its dual batteries dies, not a great feature. I use Openbox WM, with debian 10, which was installed with Gnome DE, using Upower as it's power manager. A lot of web surfing has identified Upower to be the culprit. I've tried uninstalling Upower, but that uninstalled gnome session manager and i couldn't get back in to Openbox (would only boot into terminal), so I had to reinstall gnome again (with upower).

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I only just made the switch to linux, and i really like openbox so I'd like to continue using it, I have absolutely no attachment to gnome however.

Comment: UPDATE: I've tried systemctl disable and stop upower but the problem persists!

Comment: I can confirm this is also an issue on T470s with FreeBSD 13-1 and Gnome DE. I am surprised if this is software controlled (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem did actually turn out to be a hardware issue in my case, the battery was an allegedly new, official lenovo battery with no physical signs of wear or damage. After replacing it, the problem went away!